# Efficient comparing of given token to hashed, salted tokens in the db

Tags: security, authentication, cookies, hash, access-token

I'm implementing authentication in my app using a token.

When generating a token, the actual token is sent to the client for storage in a cookie, while hashed token is saved in the database along with salt which was used during the hashing.

Now, to authenticate a user, I have to compare the given token with ones saved in the database, which seems to require checking every single entry in the database, since salt is unique for every token.

To reiterate, I'd have to do something like:

```
for saved_token in all_saved_tokens:
   hashed_token = hash_token_with_salt(actual_hash_from_client, saved_token.salt)
   if hashed_token == saved_token.hashed_token:
       return saved_token.user
```

Since that needs to happen on every call, it seems insanely inefficient.

So the question is:

**Can I somehow do it more efficiently given the way I store the info about tokens?**

I could of course store the user's username in a cookie and pass it in a call along with the password so that I can narrow down the search in the database, but ideally I'd prefer to only use a token to keep things nice and tidy.

–––

**EDIT after a couple of years**:

Now I don't actually think that there's any point in salting the tokens – they are not susceptible to rainbow attacks anyway, which were the reason for introducing salt to passwords in the first place.

Seems like there's no difference between `token + salt` and `longer_token` – if `length(longer_token) >= length(token + salt)`, we're all good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no security expert, but one idea that I've had is to split the token in two:

```
prefix   suffix
AAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
```

Then store in the database

- `sha256(prefix)`
- `salt` - Chosen at random
- `sha256(salt + prefix + suffix)`

Then you can do a lookup by `sha256(prefix)` which is unsalted.  The prefix is weak to rainbow tables, but the suffix cannot be recovered.

Answer (score 0):

why not save the hashed token to db and add an index on the hashed token so that you do not need iterate

Comment: I would need to somehow get that index, too, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0):

Hashing a short prefix is dangerous, because it could easily be bruteforced. You thus reduce the remaining attack to the bruteforce of the suffix.
It would be safer to sort the prefix of hash. This would not reveal anything about the token. While you are at it, you could add a secret in this hash (which actually makes it a hmac):
You would store

- `index` = first two bytes of `hmac_sha256(secret,token)`
- `salt` - chosen at random
- `sha256(salt + token)`

Comment: On a side note, I asked that question I long long time ago. Right now I actually think there's no point in salting the token – they are not susceptible to rainbow attacks like passwords are.